# Simple Ruby code isn't running

Tags: ruby

Can someone tell me why in the world this doesn't work? The code below is the **entire** contents of the file `prog.rb`

```
class String
    def to_b
        return true if self == "true"
        false
    end
end
```

Here is the error:

```
path/prog.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_def, expecting
<' or ';' or '\n'
             return true if self =...
                ^
```

There are no bad characters in the file and I'm using Ruby 1.9.3. The code is tested in IRB and found to work.

Is this a bug?

Thanks

Comment: BTW you could write that method simply as `def to_b; self == "true"; end`.

Comment: Works just fine; suspect your encoding or funky characters. What did you use to edit it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that there's an issue with how your editor is saving carriage returns. It's saying it expected a `<` or `;` or `\n` -- which means it didn't detect the `\n` (carriage return) that should have been present at the end of the `class String` line.

Check your editor's carriage return settings and re-save the file.

Comment: Definitely a possibility. itdoesntwork, what platform are you on and what are you using to edit the .rb file?

Comment: @bob I'm on Windows 7, using Notepad++.

Comment: @DylanMarkow Yeah, I think I accidentally set it to one of them - CR or LF, not to CR+LF. Fixed by just copying and pasting into another file :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the correct way of doing it:

```
class String
    def to_b
        return (self == "true")
    end
end
```